# Let $p \equiv 2 \mod{3}$. For any $a \in Z$ such that $ p \nmid a$ , show that there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $x^3 = a$.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p \equiv 2 \mod{3}$. For any $a \in Z$ such that $ p \nmid a$ , show that there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $x^3 = a$.

I've tried using Hensel's lemma and the fact that if $p \equiv 2 \mod{3}$ then the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection in $\mathbb{F}_p$ but have got stuck.

Comment: Hint: Show that there exists an integer $b$ such that $b^3\equiv a\pmod p$. Show that $x-b\mid x^3-a$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. Check the validity of all the assumptions in Hensel.

Comment: @JennyFirman Please be more specific about where you got stuck.  This is exactly the right approach, and it is pretty straightforward, so there's probably some small detail that you're missing.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Which $\mathbb Z_p$ do you mean in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$?  The OP seems to use this to mean $p$-adics.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure @ErickWong, but I think also Jyrki is referring to the $\;p$-adics, as Hensel's lemma strength is for these guys...

Comment: Oops. Erick is right. I should have said $x-b\mid x^3-a$ in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. All, sorry about that (I rushed things a bit to watch the bronze medal game).

Answer (score 1):

This is the easy case for modular cube roots (assuming you mean $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p)$. The explicit solution for
$a \in \mathbb{Z}_p, a\ne 0$ is $x=a^{\frac{2p-1}{3}}.\,$ First note that
$3|2p-1$ and $a^p=a.$ Now the easy calculation

$$x^3 = \left(a^{\frac{2p-1}{3}}\right)^3 = a^{2p-1}=(a^p)^2a^{-1}=a^2a^{-1}=a$$

Comment: You are interpreting that symbol to mean the integers modulo $p$, but I think it is clear from context that OP intends it to mean the $p$-adic numbers, an entirely different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 1):

Once you’ve shown that $x\mapsto x^3$ is onto in $\mathbb F_p$, you really have it. For now, to find the (and there is only one) cube root of $a\in\mathbb Z_p$ when $a\notin p\mathbb Z_p$, it’s enough to find the cube root of any $b\equiv1\pmod p$, in other words $b=1+pz$ for suitable $z\in\mathbb Z_p$. But you can also write this as $b=1+9pz'$, with again $z'\in\mathbb Z_p$. But you can easily see that the binomial expansion for $(1+9t)^{1/3}$ has no $3$’s in the denominators, in fact this series has all coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, but that’s another story. But once you know that, substituting $pz'$ for $t$ in the series gives you a $p$-adically convergent solution to the (modified) problem. Note that this bypasses Hensel (or it would if he hadn’t invented $p$-adic numbers).